# Why my azure vm not able to connect to azure database?

Tags: azure

I have a vm in azure. And I have a database as well.

I can remolty connect the azure databae from SQLMS, But When I Try to connect from my azure VM. I get A netwrok or related instance while establishing connection to the databse ?

Here is my outbond rules[image]

Any reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Check you settings for the Database Firewall, maybe it is close for your vNET, and check the NSG Rules applied to the VM. In the VM you can check connections with this:

[Connection Troubleshooting for VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEqm7.png)

Comment: not working man any issue

Comment: I have added firewall rule from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255